# Scroll issue in Expandable List View

Tags: android, sqlite, android-listview, scroll, expandablelistview

I am using an expandable list view . When i click on a parent , it displays the child information properly . However , when I scroll downwards with my child still collapsed , I get an error -bad request for field slot 0,-1 numrows=3 numcolumns=3 . When I scroll up , there is no problem .Or if my child is not collapsed , then there is no problem in scrolling anywhere.

MY code for simplecursortree adapter :-

```
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT _id,words from keywords", null);
        startManagingCursor(cursor);
                SimpleCursorTreeAdapter mAdapter = new SimpleCursorTreeAdapter(TestActivity.this,
                cursor, R.layout.exprow,
                new String[] { DbHandler.D_WORDS}, new int[] { R.id.textText},
      R.layout.row,new String[] {DbHandler.C_STATUS,DbHandler.C_CREATED_AT,DbHandler.C_USER}, new int[] {R.id.textStatus,R.id.textCreatedAt,R.id.textUser}) {

            @Override
            protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
                 dbhandler=new DbHandler(TestActivity.this);
                 SQLiteDatabase db = dbhandler.getReadableDatabase();
                    String get=groupCursor.getString(1);
                    Log.d("Post Operation", "Getting cursor for keyword = " +get);
                    String sql="SELECT status,created_at,user from tweets where words='"+get+"'" ;

                    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);
                    startManagingCursor(cursor);
                    Log.d("TestActivity","Cursor got count"+cursor.getCount());

                   db.close();
                return cursor;
            }
        };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by adding an _id in my sql query inside getChildrenCursor . I thought the _id just has to be present in the table .

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem with data for each parent.
please check